# How does the item() function works when accessing pixel values?

Tags: python, opencv

I was reading the OpenCV python tutorials, and they said that the NumPy array function item() is the best way to access pixel values in an image, but I don't understand what it does.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

print(img.item(10, 10, 2)) # I don't know what the item() function does/what it's parameters are
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html): `numpy.ndarray.item()` copies an element of an array to a standard Python scalar and returns it.

To put it in other words, calling `img.item(i)` gets you a copy of the value represented by the index `i` in your array, similar to `img[i]` but with the difference that it returns it as a Python scalar instead of an array. Following the docs, getting a Python scalar is useful to speed up access to the elements of the array and doing arithmetic on the values taking advantage of Python's optimized math.

An example:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(9, size=(3, 3))
>>> x
array([[1, 8, 4],
      [8, 7, 5],
      [2, 1, 1]])
>>> x.item((1,0))
8
>>> x[1,0] # both calls seem to return the same value, but...
8
>>> type(x[1,0]) # Numpy's own int32
<class 'numpy.int32'>
>>> type(x.item((1,0))) # Python's standard int
<class 'int'>
```

`item` takes only one parameter which can be `None`, which only works with single item arrays, an `int_type`, which works like a flat index, and a `tuple` of `int_type`, which is interpreted as a multi dimension index of the array.

Going back to your concrete question, [OpenCV recommends](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) `item` and `itemset` when working with individual pixel values, as `numpy` is optimized for array calculations so accessing a single item is discouraged.

So instead of doing:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img[0, 0] = 255 # Setting a single pixel
px = img[0, 0]  # Getting a single pixel
```

Do:

```
img.itemset((0, 0), 255)
px = img.item((0, 0))
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks. But why did the documentation give the scalar as  3 values, instead of 2.

Comment: @VarunMehrotra I'm not entirely sure what part of the documentation you're referencing, so maybe if you're more specific I can answer that question better. Nonetheless, I think you're talking about the `item` and `itemset` examples. I believe OpenCV uses 3 values because they're working with tree dimensional arrays, while I just used 2 in my example for simplicity, nothing more.

Comment: I was referring to the https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#basic-ops link in the item() and itemset() functions. I was confused about why it references 3 values on a 2d image.

Comment: I was thinking, does the 3rd value mean channel? That's my best guess because it is a color image.

Comment: It seems to be the BGR values of a the specific pixel you're getting: _it returns an array of Blue, Green, Red values_. So if you get, say `[255, 255, 255]` that would be a white pixel.